# Не могу завершить программу через sys.exit(0)

Tags: python, многопоточность

В программе выполняется куча задач, куча потоков, и почему-то через sys.exit(0) не закрываются все потоки и не завершается программа. Я пробовал для каждого потока делать while не True а Done, и делать Done на False, но что-то не срабатывает. Как еще можно принудительно закрыть программу?

Comment: а логи что говорят ?

Comment: Логи ничего не говорят, просто программа работает как будто и не завершал, но команда точно сработала, т.к. перед ней идет сообщение о том что она закрывается, и оно выводится

Comment: А ты после поставь .Посматри после выйдет  в логах что либо .Наверника есть какаята фича костыльного закрытия

Comment: После не выводит ничего.

Comment: Проверь какой поток жив.Может у тебя утечка???или ещё хуже клонирование .Дебаж.Ищи того живиго.найди его и прямым обращение заверши

Comment: А можно как-то в модуле threading послать сигнал на завершение потоков? Или только естественное окончание программы?

Comment: поток  можно начать остановить возобновить и отменить.У тебя скорее всего она идет в глобалку.

Answer (score -2):

```
for iThreadNumber in range(len(aServerHosts)):
            if (Threads[iThreadNumber].is_alive()):
                Threads[iThreadNumber]._Thread__stop()
```

/---------------------------------

```
import threading
import time
import subprocess
import thread
class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def init(self, app_to_run, args,**kwargs):
super(StoppableThread, self).init(args,**kwargs)
self.stop = threading.Event()
self.handle = subprocess.Popen(appto_run, shell=False)

    def stop(self):
subprocess.Popen("taskkill /F /T /PID %i"%self.handle.pid , shell=True)
self.stop.set()


    def stopped(self):
        return self.stop.isSet()

thread = StoppableThread("c:\run.cmd")
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
time.sleep(5)
thread.stop()
```

eбивать потоки это уже крайность ,и не советую но ты сделай костыль потом оптимизашку добавишь)

Comment: Теперь можно объяснения что за aServerHosts и Threads? Мой питон на них ругается